# How to add parent key value to all child items in js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json where one parent array, and every object of parent array there is another child array `pozzles`.

So what I want to do is, there is one key-value(`title`) of parent item I want to add in every item of child array.

Check this json screen shot to understand clear.

[image]

Is there any direct method available in `js` to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your data

```
const data = [{ id: 1, title: "some", pozzles: [{ id: "1A" }, { id: "1B" }] }, { id: 2, title: "some2", pozzles: [{ id: "2A" }, { id: "2B" }] }];

data.forEach(d => {
    d.pozzles.forEach(p => { p.title = d.title })
});
```